# Notification without any Action?

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to have a Notification without any Action? I want to display download progress to user and after download completion, inform user that download is finished and user can clear the notification. I don't want to start another Activity when user clicks on Notification. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: have you even tried before asking this question ?

Comment: If you know the answer, reply. Otherwise go to the next question.

Comment: merely trying to clarify in order to avoid suggesting something you may already have attempted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a notification and don't attach a PendingIntent to it.

Comment: I passed `null` as this: `notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, null);` and I got exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required: pkg=com.example id=2...` Any idea?

Comment: Try putting `new Intent()` instead of passing null for the intent.

Comment: Works! and if I want to clear notification on user click?

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad In that case you'll need to pass an Intent to a service or receiver from which you can run the code to cancel the notification. You can't do it from an empty intent.

Comment: Checkout my comment here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16045842/892500