# Android - notificationManager.notify doesn't display notification

Tags: android

I'm trying to show a simple local notification message on Android.Here is my code but I'm not able to make it work.

There is no action:

```
final Context context = this;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    Notification n=new Notification.Builder(context)
                                    .setContentTitle("Nabeeer?")
                                    .setContentText("Iceriiik")
                                    .setContentIntent(null)
                                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                                    .build();

                            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                            notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an icon to your notification:

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.youricon)
```

This isn't documented in the official docs: you need to add a small icon, else [the notification won't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045722/notification-not-showing).