# Notification not showing up in android 19

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to notify using notification as below: The main activity has the following code, but nothing is showing up.

```
 mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setContentTitle("Enable Call Permission")
                            .setContentText("Please Enable or Accept call permission");
            int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;

            Intent targetIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PermissionActivity.class);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
            save();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it doesnt work without an icon.

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon);
```

see this post:

[Notification Not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045722/notification-not-showing)